# Duda de la función de PDO lastInserId() a la hora de traer el id de una conexión

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy usando PDO de PHP y MySQL y tengo entendido que la función lastInsertId() me trae el ultimo Id de una consulta pero lo que no logro comprender es si esta función me devuelve el ultimo Id de una consulta según su conexión, hago esta pregunta porque quiero evitarme futuros errores ya que esto lo podría implementar desde diferentes conexiones y no quiero que al usar esta función simultáneamente pueda ocasionar algún tipo de error como traerme un Id que no es de esa conexión.

Aquí una parte de mi código que creo que puede presentar la falla anteriormente planteada, primero hago una consulta de inserción en donde $codproyecto es un autoincremental.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO proyecto VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

$stmt->execute([$codproyecto, $titulo,$descripcion,$problema,$solucion,$alcance, $fechainicio, $fechafinal, $numeroestudiantes, $codestadop]);
```

Luego obtengo el ID anteriormente insertado con la función lastInsertId() y procedo a ingresarla en una nueva consulta.

```
$codproyect = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarioproyecto VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

$stmt->execute([$codusuarioproyecto, $codusuario, $codproyect]);
```

Pienso que para una sola conexión estaría bien, pero para múltiples puede que me obtenga el id de otra conexión, pero esto solo es una suposición, espero que me ayuden a resolver esta duda, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Hay discusiones sobre la duda que planteas (SO en inglés) y no recuerdo ahora mismo si se llegó a una conclusión definitiva ni cual ha sido. De todos modos falta algo fundamental en tu pregunta: ¿te interesa el último último ID o te interesa el último ID generado por esa conexión? Pongo  un ejemplo (independiente de conexión persistente o no): una web con miles, millones de usuarios con capacidad de insertar... entra usuario `1` e inserta el ID `7` ... desde China entra usuario 2 en inserta ID `8`, desde Rusia un hacker intenta 500 inserciones fallidas (dado que tampoco controlas...

Comment: ... cosas como esas, el último ID exitoso que ocurra será el `508`, sí sí, el 508). Bien, entra un usuario normalito desde Italia e inserta el ID `508`. La pregunta es: ¿en tu pregunta, cuál es el ID que te interesa conocer **en el contexto del usuario 1**? Y, otra pregunta clave para estos casos: ¿para qué uso quieres obtener el ID?

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente (*a menos que tengas una conexión persistente*), `lastInsertId()` siempre te dará el último ID (auto_increment) insertado para la conexión activa y, para evitarte dolores de cabeza, sigue estos pasos:

> 1. Evita crear conexiones nuevas para cada consulta

Dependiendo de la configuración del servidor, solo vas a tener disponible cierta cantidad de conexiones simultáneas y, si creas una por cada consulta, puedes llegar a ver el error `Too many connections` cuando hay varios usuarios visitando tu página o, incluso, puede ser que en la misma petición

> 2. Usa solo una conexión a base de datos en toda la petición

A menos que tengas requerimientos muy específicos y realmente debas tener otra conexión a base de datos, usa siempre solo una. Ejemplo:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usuario, $contraseña);
```

Asegúrate de que todos tus scripts y funciones tengan acceso a esa variable, ya sea usando `global` (mala práctica), enviando por parámetro (un poco mejor), inyectando dependencia (OK) o por medio de una clase y un método, probablemente estático, (OK)

> 3. Obtén el ID insertado inmediatamente

Siempre que necesites saber el ID del registro que acabas de insertar, ejecuta `lastInsertId()` justo después de la inserción:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO proyecto VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$codproyecto, $titulo,$descripcion,$problema,$solucion,$alcance, $fechainicio, $fechafinal, $numeroestudiantes, $codestadop]);

$codproyect = $pdo->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarioproyecto VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->execute([$codusuarioproyecto, $codusuario, $codproyect]);
```

Esto lo estás haciendo bien y no va a haber errores. Si otros usuarios están haciendo modificaciones en tu sitio, no va a afectar el resultado, porque cada uno está trabajando con su propia conexión independiente y en cada una `lastInsertId()` devolverá el valor adecuado.

**Nota:** Nunca he trabajado con conexiones persistentes, por lo que no puedo aportar información útil al respecto.